# Why is Spring Data still using null references as return values?

Tags: spring-data

This is more a suggestion for improvement than a question.

We all know about Tony Hoare's "billion dollar mistake" by inventing the null reference. Google advices in the wiki of the [guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to [avoid using null](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).

I really appreciate the Spring Data project and we use Spring Data MongoDB in many projects. Is there a chance that you will replace all possible null reference return values by an `Optional<T>`? I think this would be a big improvement when using the Spring Data repositories abstraction.

I know that a lot of the interfaces would have to be changed, but the code changes are almost trivial, just wrap the return type in an `Optional.of(returnValue)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guava/JDK8 `Optional<T>` support has already been introduced with RC1 of Release Train [Dijkstra](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release%20Train%20Dijkstra). Please have a look at the [spring-data-examples for java8](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/java8) to see how it works.

```
interface CustomerRepository extends Repository<Customer, Long> {

  // CRUD method using Optional
  Optional<Customer> findOne(Long id);

  // Query method using Optional
  Optional<Customer> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

BTW: there's support for *default methods* as well.

Comment: You can't have findOne with Optional as this method already exist with return type Customer without Optional

Comment: findOne without Optional is only present in CrudRepository. This answer works if your interface extends Repository.

Answer (score 1):

I think, once Spring Data can drop the support for JDK versions older than JDK 8, it should be fairly easy to use the JDK 8 Optional. However, since this would change the whole API, you would have to release a new major version, along with upgrade paths etc. (the code change would be trivial, but not the consequences for the users of Spring Data).

Comment: In fact they must not drop the JDK support for older version, because they could easily implement their own version of the Optional, like the guava team did.

And you are right, that it should be on a new major version, because of the massive API changes. But I think it is really worth to do it.

Comment: You can create a feature request in JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO

Answer (score 1):

With the latest and greatest versions of Spring Data [the CrudRepository now actually returns `Optional](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.java#L54)